# Finding unique letters in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find out how to find the amount of unique letters in a string.

I know how to find the amount of unique characters in a string by using the code below.

But what if I want to find the amount of unique letters, not characters, excluding punctuation,in the string?

```
    import string
    s = 'AabC'
    s = s.lower()
    print(sum(1 for c in string.ascii_lowercase if s.count(c) == 1))
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you trying to get.

Comment: Should the output be the total number of unique letters or the frequency of unique letters?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can filter out all non-letter characters, then you can convert it into a `set` and check the length.

```
s = 'AabC123qwer!!>>??'
unique = set(filter(str.isalpha, s.lower()))

print(len(unique))
```

---

```
7
```